# Visual studio SQL default value not showing on windows form when adding new record

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, default-value

I have created a SQL table in Visual studio and set a default value on a field.

[image]

The table is connected to my C# project (in the same solution) and pulls through fine, however the default values are not appearing when a new row is created via a windows form.

[image]

Info from comment questions:

- It doesn't appear on the form when I click the + for a new row.
- When a row is added from the database the defaults are there.
- Added a new row via the form, left the fields with default values blank, saved, re opened and no default values.

Comment: Do you mean the default value is not being set on the database when saving or it does not appear in the forms application before you save?

Comment: @SBFrancies It doesnt appear on the form when i click the + for a new row

Comment: The default value will appear in the database if you do an insert without specifying a value for that column. If you want to set it automatically in the form I think you will have to do it manually in the code.

Comment: Can it not be automatically pulled into the text box when a new row is created on the form?

Comment: You would have to Save the new row first, then open it again in your form

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. I just wanted to clarify if the issue was in the database or the application. I know in a web form you would have to set the value in the application.

Comment: Tried that, there is no values in them after i save and reopen

Comment: Add a new row in SQL only, check that that is working...Your Form could have overwritten the default values

Comment: Do you have MS SQL Server Management Studio?  This is the better interface for ad hoc queries...You could use an INSERT expression to add a new row, or use Mgt Studio to Edit records, add new row

Comment: What is your data access layer? is it entity framework? It depends entirely on how you create the new record. If it's entity framework, it probably won't honour the default, it'll probably explicitly insert NULL

Comment: Perhaps it’s just “bound” meaning that you just set the form properties and point it at a database  and a table. (Rather than writing any special code). Did you follow a guide to connect the form to the DB? Can you link to it? Basically it is explicitly inserting a blank rather than not specifying anything.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I published my sql project then just added the data via the data soruce wizard to my forms project

Comment: Default value will not show until you save the row to the database

Comment: @Hadi SO your saying there is no way to show a default value on a form when creating a new row?

Comment: @Matt you can add it programatically, but the Default value option used in SQL Server, is to assign a value if there is no values provided in this column

Comment: Can you provide the code behind that Save button?

Comment: Maybe just populate the default values into the text boxes when they click on New Vehicle.  That way, user can see what will be entered into database.

Comment: OK, you set default values in DB table. Are you set default values in the [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/specify-default-values-for-new-rows-in-the-datagrid)?

Comment: Are you using data binding? Are you set devault values for DataTable [columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.defaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [W3Schools Tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp)

> The default value will be added to all new records IF no other value is specified.

So the Default value will not show until you save the row to the database, you can add it programatically, but the Default value constraint is used to assign a value if there is no values provided in this column

You can [save these default values in the application Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) and use it when new row is added

```
textBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.TextBoxDefaultValue;
```

If you are facing an issue when defining default value in Visual Studio try adding a Default Constraint using SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE XXX 
ADD CONSTRAINT def_Retired
DEFAULT 'N' FOR Retired;
```

**UPDATE 1**

On the form designer, click on the BindingNavigator, In the Properties window  set the `AddNewItem` property to `(none)`

Try adding the following code to the `bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click` event

```
private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

 vehiclesBindingSource.AddNew();
 Textbox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Text1default;

};
```

Comment: I am getting an error on a similar form saying employeeID cannot be blank when i click add new. it doesnt have the `xxsource.EndEdit();` in it either

Comment: What are the constraint on employeeID? Remeber to do this step `On the form designer, click on the BindingNavigator, In the Properties window set the AddNewItem property to (none)`

Comment: Thats the step i missed :) Im going to write that down!

Answer (score 2):

> It doesn't appear on the form when I click the + for a new row.

The `DataGridView` does not know anything about default values in the database table. Accordingly, you must [specify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/specify-default-values-for-new-rows-in-the-datagrid) the default values in the `DataGridView`.

Or if you are using data binding, you can [specify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.defaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) default values in the `DataTable`.

> When a row is added from the database the defaults are there.

It's right, because in the database they are set.

> Added a new row via the form, left the fields with default values blank, saved, re opened and no default values.

If you insert data into the database in the following way:

```
insert into SomeTable ('Retired') values ('');
```

then no default value will be used. With high probability I can assume that at the moment you passes empty values from DataGridView, if they are not set. This is wrong!

If you insert data into the database in the following way:

```
insert into SomeTable ('Last Mileage') values (0);
```

then the default value for `Retired` column will be used. It should be so.

Therefore, you must correctly design the `Insert` statement, completely omitting those columns for which should be used the default value in the database itself.

---

Summing up. You either have to fill the default values in the `DataGridView`/`DataTable` or dynamically construct the `Insert` statement, completely omitting the not specified values.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning default values in forms that are dynamically generated.  You may need to evaluate whether the components of your client side/server side scripting were also made to accommodate this dynamic behavior in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Default Constraint Works only if you are not specifying the Column in the Insert List.

Suppose I have a Table Like This

```
CREATE TABLE MyInfo
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Nm VARCHAR(50),
    MyDate DATE DEFAULT(GETDATE())
)
```

I'm specifying the Values Like this

```
INSERT INTO MyInfo
(
    Nm,
    MyDate
)
SELECT
    Nm = 'A',
    MyDate = '02/23/93'
UNION
SELECT
    Nm = 'B',
    MyDate = NULL
```

And The Result will be Like this

[image]

Now I insert a row without specifying `MyDate` Column

```
INSERT INTO MyInfo
(
    Nm
)
VALUES('C')
```

And the MyDate was populated bu Default values

[image]

Default Constraint is meant to assign the value if the column is not specified in the insert list. If what you need is to set a Default value if The Inserted value IS NULL or empty, Try using triggers